# Agregar nuevas ubicaciones en una ruta del plugin MapQuest en Leaflet

Tags: javascript, gps, leaflet, mapquest

no tengo mucha experiencia en javascript pero quiero saber si es posible insertar nuevos latLng con un push o algo parecido. **no se como hacerlo, me ayudadas con un ejemplo, Gracias!**

Tengo dos variables

```
var longitud, latitud
```

estas variables le asigno valores con una solicitud asincrona (eso funciona bien).
pero para crear marcadores en el mapa de mapquest y unir esos marcadores con la ruta debo de ejecutar esto en especifico:

```
 map.addLayer(MQ.routing.routeLayer({
  directions: dir,
  fitBounds: true
}));
```

**el problema esta en que no he podido insertar nuevos items dentro de locations:**

```
locations: [
      { latLng: { lat: 8.272839, lng: -62.744363 } },
      { latLng: { lat: 8.262194, lng: -62.743719 } },
      { latLng: { lat: 8.278074, lng: -62.727841 } },
      { latLng: { lat: latitud, lng: longitud } }

    ]
```

aqui esta un fragmento .js

```
    var map,
  dir;

map = L.map('map', {
  layers: MQ.mapLayer(),
  center: [ 38.895345, -77.030101 ],
  zoom: 15
});

dir = MQ.routing.directions();

dir.route({
        locations: [
          { latLng: { lat: 8.272839, lng: -62.744363 } },
          { latLng: { lat: 8.262194, lng: -62.743719 } },
          { latLng: { lat: 8.278074, lng: -62.727841 } }
        ]
      });
// como inserto otro elemento a locations?? en esta linea antes de graficar en el mapa
map.addLayer(MQ.routing.routeLayer({
  directions: dir,
  fitBounds: true
}));
```

Pagina que empleo como referencia

[Routing Plugin for Leaflet](https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/leaflet-plugins/routing/)

[pagina de Mapquest](https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/mapquest-js/v1.3/)

Comment: Es un array de objetos, así que si es posible con un push, pero sé más especifico por favor, porque si esa es la pregunta entonces con este comentario ya tienes la respuesta... Te sugiero que vayas a [ask] para poder mejorar la calidad de tu pregunta. Recuerda que mientras más detalle nos des entonces tendrás respuestas con mayor calidad... Te reitero, por favor lee el enlace de [ask] para más información... Bienvenido a SO en español!!!

Comment: Gracias, acabo de cambiar la pregunta y otorgue mas detalles. Espero haber sido mas especifico

Comment: Como seria el codigo para insertar ese nuevo item en locations?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que te están faltando algunas comillas en ese código considero que lo correcto debería de ser algo así:

```
div.route({"locations": [{"latLng": {lat: 8.272839, lng: -62.744363}}, { "latLng": { lat: 8.262194, lng: -62.743719 }},{ "latLng": { lat: 8.278074, lng: -62.727841 }}]});
```

Comment: Bienvenido wrtfix, esa es la respuesta a su pregunta?? Si no lo es y solo quieres aportar con un comentario entonces hazlo en el lugar correspondiente a los comentarios... Date una vuelta por [answer] para más información...

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]